# Swift - popViewController after Dismiss

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to dismiss viewcontroller presented as modal("Present Modally") and then popViewController in navigationController. Here is my storyboard, I want to go from QRScanner VC to Monitoring VC.

[image]

Here is how I'm presenting QRScanner VC in Add Device VC:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryboardIDs.MainStoryboard, bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: VCIDs.QRDeviceScannerVC) as! QRDeviceScannerVC
controller.deviceName = deviceNameTxt.text
present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Here is how I'm trying to go back to MonitoringVC:

```
self?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated:true)?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
```

Also tried:

```
self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    self?.presentingVC?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
})
```

It always goes to the Add Device VC instead of Monitoring VC

Comment: It looks like there is a mistake in your storyboard? There seem to be two push segues running from Monitoring to Add Device.

Comment: There is 2 buttons that opens add device. 1 of them is hidden when user already has at least 1 device registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with

```
self?.dismiss(animated: false, completion:nil)
self?.presentingVC?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Just check if you have reference to the navigation controller

Comment: for some reason navigationController is nil :/

Comment: and presentingVC is AddDevice or the modal? Also, did you push AddDevice or present?

Comment: It looks like `let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController` is returning `UITabBarController`. I used `present` to show the QRScannerVC

Comment: and what is this self?  you can try directly with self instead of self.presentingViewController

Comment: `self` returns `QRDeviceScannerVC` and 'self.navigationController` also returns nil :/

Comment: In general, there is no problem with calling dismiss and after that pop. You can have a problem with animations, and this is the reason why in my code the first one is without animation. But you can call dismiss on your navigation controller and after that pop and it should work fine.

Comment: yes, this is the problem try to get a reference to the navigation controller and it will be fine. Or just trigger my code in the AddDevice controller.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use an *unwind segue*, with the unwind target method located in the Monitoring VC. All the right stuff will just happen as if by magic.